# Cross mobile platform interface navigation

Tags: mobile, navigation, web-app, responsive-design

I have to architect a mobile web responsive interface that will be the same for iOS and Android clients.

The app has several *areas* which I would like to switch using **bottom navigation/tabs with icons ans text** design where I would display 5 items of which the last one would be *More...*. So this is the first level.

But then some of these areas have on-page components which I would like to users to switch between. For this I was thinking of top scrollable tabs with text only representation. Something similar to what Medium uses in their mobile app. I could also display these individual components as collapsible drawers but that means that users would need to scroll down to get to those and the whole thing will become rather messy because individual drawer components consist of filters, data and maybe even additional actions. And since users would be focusing on just a singl one at a time I was thinking it would be better to have tabbed navigation at the top to select a specific component and just display its features.

### Question

My app clearly has a two-level complex navigation where first level selects app area but second level switches context of the area. I wonder whether my idea of using bottom navigation in combination with top scrollable/Swipeable tab would work ok? I would like to simplify this or at least use some sort of controls that would work cross mobile platform without confusing users.

Is there any existing mobile app that uses this complex navigation, but maybe using different means of components?

**Have I forgotten about anything else?**

Comment: Can you focus this more around a single question? This site is designed for single questions and their answers. It doesn't really work well if you have multiple ones. I think you can restructure this all around the same single concept, but if not then you can post separate questions for your other queries.

Comment: @JonW That's arguably true. I've number-listed my questions so answering becomes clear. All of these questions are related between each other as they're all about complex two level navigation hence they can't be separated into a multiple posts unfortunately. Question structuring in numbered list simplifies structuring of answers just as well.

Comment: My concern is that it could lead to people only answering one of the bullet-points rather than the whole lot. Questions need to be singularly answerable. If person A answers point 1 really well but ignores part 2 and 3, but someone else answers those really well, which would you mark as correct?

Comment: Taken from a distance, this feels like "design my app for me, and prove your design choices with credible references demonstrating similar approaches for similar problems."

Comment: Only you, @RobertKoritnik can fully know the extent of your specifications, so I strongly suggest a long, slow meandering visit to the sites that show new UI and UX thinking, and the works of masters. And then download and try as many apps as you can that come close to the level of complexity and problems you're solving.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find exact inspiration from within this browsing, as you're obviously both highly intelligent and highly opinionated, and got very high expectations of final user experience. You won't find anyone willing to understand and make recommendations to your standards in free website services like this. You're probably a very good programmer deserving of very good design work. They're both premium services.

Comment: @Confused you surely got me confused. The point is that my proposed navigation seems too complicated to me. I'm trying to come up with some different approach that someone else might've designed already. Standard components don't seem to get me the best solution.